# html displays image, jQuery doesn't

Tags: jquery, html, hover

I have html code that displays an image thus:

```
<p class="word_set">2<span class="color_up audio" id="b1e02">and</span><span class="color_up  audio" id="b1t02">และ</span><span class="ws_dialog_icon"><img src="/templates/beez_20/images/e2tw/lamp_non-hover_20.png" alt="light bulb" height="20px" width="20px"></span></p>
```

I want the image to change when the mouse hovers, so in this jquery code, the hover works for the first text hi-lighting statement, no problem, but in the second hover statement the images do not change as the mouse hovers:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("span.color_up").hover(

    function () {
        jQuery(this).css({
            "color": "red"
        });
    },

    function () {
        jQuery(this).css({
            "color": "black"
        });
    });
    jQuery("span.ws_dialog_icon").hover(

    function () {
        jQuery(this).attr("src", "/templates/beez_20/images/e2tw/lamp_hover_20.png");
        alert("hover");
    },

    function () {
        jQuery(this).attr("src", "/templates/beez_20/images/e2tw/lamp_non-hover_20.png");
    });
});
```

the alert displays showing the second hover statement is being accessed. Also, lamp_hover_20.png is displayed in the html when substituted for the non-hover image.
I can't see what's wrong here, tho it's probably pretty obvious. Any help, much appreciated, for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You tried to change `src` of `span`, you need to search inside span the `img`

change this:

```
jQuery("span.ws_dialog_icon").hover(
        function() {
          jQuery(this).attr("src","/templates/beez_20/images/e2tw/lamp_hover_20.png");
          alert("hover");
        },
        function() {
          jQuery(this).attr("src","/templates/beez_20/images/e2tw/lamp_non-hover_20.png");
        }
      );
```

to this:

```
jQuery("span.ws_dialog_icon").hover(
        function() {
          jQuery(this).find('img').attr("src","/templates/beez_20/images/e2tw/lamp_hover_20.png");
          alert("hover");
        },
        function() {
          jQuery(this).find('img').attr("src","/templates/beez_20/images/e2tw/lamp_non-hover_20.png");
        }
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think jQuery(this) will refer to the span, not the img, in the jQuery("span.ws_dialog_icon").

Try

```
jQuery(this).find('img').attr(..
```